# Programmatically change device orientation in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have navigation based app, when I click on any row in root view, the next view should come in Landscape mode.

I am not able to find a proper way to implement this. What I tried is:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {   
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

But this is not working. The view should open only in Landscape mode (not when user rotate it).

Answer (score 2):

My sandbox app:
https://github.com/comonitos/programatical_device_orientation

The solution is easy:

in interface (h file) :

```
    BOOL rotated;
```

in implementation (m file):
1. rewrite

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
    return rotated;
    }
```

2 call [self setup]

```
    -(void) setup { 
    rotated = YES; 
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft]; 
    rotated = NO; 
    }
```

Comment: You Are awesome... You don't know how much time i have wasted to search The Solution for my problem Here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654670/mpmovieplayercontroller-does-not-change-orientation-in-full-screen-mode-in-ios-5.....and your answer and code have helped me many ways to achieve the solution.... thanx man...+1

Answer (score 0):

you can force your Device to change Orientation.......using magic line in View will Appear

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

All the Best..

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, it worked but showing a warning. I think its private function we can't use

Comment: setOrientation isn't a method in UIDevice

Comment: @AppleDelegate This is quite an old answer which worked in previous iOS version.I am not sure about using it in iOS 6 as i haven't tested it yet.

Comment: This was working well in earlier version of iOS i.e till iSO 4 & 5.May be this has been deprecated in iOS 6.And this was the solution for @iPhoneDev when he asked couple of years back.

Answer (score 0):

Try designing your view in landscape mode and in it's view controller, and in

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {   
   .....
}
```

return No for portrait orientation and YES for landscape orientation
This will display your view in landscape mode.

Comment: I tried this, but its not working, probably because its an Navigation app

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code from my landscape-view based app:

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }

}
```

Put this in a landscape-based viewcontroller to have it display only in landscape mode and to switch between landscape left and landscape right.  You will also need your xib to be landscape based.