# How to display in landscape mode in portrait?

Tags: iphone

I have a calculator screen in Iphone, when i launched it  displayed in portrait,but i want to display the calculator screen in landscape mode from portrait and also change the orientation, how?

I tried the source code:

```
      self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
      self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI * (90) / 180.0)); 
      self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480, 320);
```

It is used first time launched only landscape mode in portrait, but change the orientation not working, any one help me.

Comment: I think you want to run your app in both orientation..... m i right.. otherwise please tell me what you exact want to do.....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
[[self view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
[[self view] setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
[[self view] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2)];
```

Comment: I use these code, it was launching landscape in portrait mode, but   change the orientation not working, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        return YES
    }

Now make use of any one method for ur rotation 
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
    Hope this help.
```

Answer (score 0):

THE [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559828/programmatically-change-device-orientation-in-iphone/9496879#9496879) here

My sandbox app:
https://github.com/comonitos/programatical_device_orientation

The solution is easy:

in interface (h file) :

```
    BOOL rotated;
```

in implementation (m file):
1. rewrite

```
    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
    return rotated;
    }
```

2 call [self setup]

```
    -(void) setup { 
    rotated = YES; 
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft]; 
    rotated = NO; 
    }
```